# Store generics in class properties in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have my own small library for doing http requests to our api server. We have paginated responses so I want my library to handle them nicely. My desire is to have something like `Array.reduce()`. Ideally it would look like this:

```
Get("http://myapi.com/someData")
  .onPage(initialValue: [String](), combine: {valueSoFar /*[String]*/, jsonData in
    if let arrayOfStrings = jsonData as? [String] {
      for string in arrayOfStrings {
        valueSoFar.append(string)
      }
    }
    return valueSoFar
  })
  .onComplete({finalValue in
    //Do stuff with finalValue
  })
```

I can't figure out how to define this though. So far I have something that looks like this:

```
func Get(url: String) -> Session {return Session(url)}

class Session {
  var pageCallback: /*what goes here?*/
  var completeCallback: /*what goes here?*/
  var valueSoFar: /*what goes here?*/

  func onPage<T>(initialValue: T, combine: (T, JSON) -> T) -> Session {
    valueSoFar = initialValue
    pageCallback = combine
    return self
  }

  func onComplete<T>(callback: (T) -> Void) -> Session {
    completeCallback = callback
    return self
  }

  func calledWhenNewPageFromServer(jsonData: JSON) {
    valueSoFar = pageCallback(valueSoFar, jsonData)
    if noMorePages {completeCallback(valueSoFar)}
  }
}
```

I can't figure out what those type signatures for those generic properties should be.

Comment: Can you define it as AnyObject for the initialisation? `var pageCallback: AnyObject?`

Comment: Unfortunately no... There's no compile error when I assign the closure, but there's a compile error when I try to call it later "Cannot call value of non-function type 'AnyObject'"

Comment: Actually I take that back, I can't even assign to AnyObject?. I can assign to Any? though. Still a similar error when trying to call it though "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>')"